# Java snmp does not get tree leaves

Tags: java, snmp4j

I am trying to retrieve leaves of a MIB tree with the SNMP-walk command using the Java code below, with no success. I am using the SNMP4J framework to interact with the other SNMP end of the application. 
My test case is to retrieve the maxPhases scalar from the MIB, which is a parameter inside the NTCIP protocol (transportation system protocol from the US government).
The other end of the application is built using the net-snmp framework (C/C++), where a use case is shown in the *RESULTDS*.
The example image can retrieve the maxPhases and the maxPhaseGroups values (both INTEGER 24).
I am using SHA for authentication and AES128 to encrypt the data (system will be deployed using the internet, so we need the security layer).

```
public static String doSnmpwalk() throws IOException { 
        Snmp snmp = null; 
        TransportMapping transport = null; 

        try { 

            Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse("udp:" + targetAddr + "/" + portNum); 
            transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping(); 
            snmp = new Snmp(transport);

            USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(), new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID()), 0);
            SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

            snmp.getUSM().addUser(new OctetString("user"),
                    new UsmUser(new OctetString("SHAAES"), AuthSHA.ID, new OctetString("12345678"), PrivAES128.ID, new OctetString("91234567")));

            transport.listen(); 

            UserTarget target = new UserTarget();
            target.setAddress(targetAddress);
            target.setRetries(1);
            target.setTimeout(5000);
            target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
            target.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
            target.setSecurityName(new OctetString("SHAAES"));

            OID oid = new OID(oidStr); 
            OID [] oidArray  = new OID[1];
            oidArray[0] = oid;

            DefaultPDUFactory defaultPDUFactory = new DefaultPDUFactory(PDU.GETBULK); 
            TreeUtils treeUtils = new TreeUtils(snmp, defaultPDUFactory); 

            //List<TreeEvent> events = treeUtils.getSubtree(target, oid);

            List<TreeEvent> events = treeUtils.walk(target, oidArray);

            if (events == null || events.size() == 0) { 
                return null; 
            } 

            // Get snmpwalk result. 
            for (TreeEvent event : events) { 
                if (event.isError()) { 
                   // LOGGER.error("OID has an error: {}", event.getErrorMessage()); 
                } else { 
                    VariableBinding[] varBindings = event.getVariableBindings(); 
                    if (varBindings == null || varBindings.length == 0) { 
                        //System.out.println("VarBinding: No result returned."); 
                    } 
                    for (VariableBinding varBinding : varBindings) { 
                        varBinding.toValueString(); 
                        results += (varBinding.getOid().toString() + "=" + varBinding.getVariable().toString()) + "\n"; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } finally { 
            if (snmp!=null) snmp.close(); 
            if (transport!=null) transport.close(); 
        } 

        return results; 
    }
```

**Results:**

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1206.4.2.1.1.1.0 = INTEGER: 24
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1206.4.2.1.1.3.0 = INTEGER: 24
```

Comment: The content of the image is unreadable. Also please rather just post the output instead of making a screenshot.

Comment: Please don't include an image when you can include actual code within your question. Please have a look to [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Sorry guys, I just update my post.

Comment: So whats your question again?

Comment: i am trying to get in Java the '24 phases'. But I can't.

Answer (score 0):

The question was wrongly phrased, because SNMP4J actually returns the leaf objects' values. The author of the question, according to his last comment above, is looking for the MIB information associated with the object ID he gets back.

That info is no transferred over the wire, but is static information from the corresponding MIB specification. SNMP4J-SMI-PRO or other MIB parsers can be used to get that info too. SNMP4J-SMI-PRO will do that seamlessly when the content of the Variable or VariableBinding is converted into a string. It uses the DISPLAY-HINT information and the OBJECT-TYPE SYNTAX from the MIB specification for that.